# Login not working on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I cannot login on Drupal 7.
The problem is very strange:
- If I enter incorrect credentials, i have an error message
- If I enter correct credentials,  form is posted but user is not logged in
I'm using the login block

Comment: are you using a subdomain or a subfolder or something like that? where is your site when you look in the url-bar in your browser?

Comment: The login form post to /frontpage.
I have a doubt of a cache problem... If i ctrl+F5 the login work properly